# External monitor (LG 27ML600M) looks blurry 75hz

Tags: mac, display

I have a [LG 27ML600M](https://www.lg.com/au/it-monitors/lg-27ML600M-B) monitor that supports 75hz.

When I set Mac OS to 75hz in the display settings it looks blurry. If I set it back to 60hz it looks normal. Any ideas on why this is happening?

**Specs**

2010 Mac Pro with the AMD 5770 graphics card.

Comment: Which interface are you using, analog DSUB or digital HDMI? What resolution you are using, 1920x1080p or something else? Have you read the manual and tried to enable or disable the "1ms Motion Blur Reduction" setting in the menu?

Comment: LG are not particularly good monitors in my opinion.  I dumped a new one because of poor performance and switched to View Sonic.

Comment: Official specs say 60 Hz. I suggest you stick with it.

Comment: @DanielB the box said 75hz and my windows pc does 75hz fine so it might be a mac thing.

Comment: Apple have not traditionally cared about going above 60Hz, even on newer Macs. I'd just stick to 60. I still have several old cheesegraters in the building, but none of them have screens capable of more than 60 & no documentation seems to exist that would say the cards can do more.

Comment: Do you have any adapters between the monitor and your Mac? If you could try and change that. Or perhaps another cable. I have tried _a surprising amount of times_ where adapters or cables have been faulty and screwed stuff like this up. ... But it also sounds like quite an old installation you have yourself there. I mean - you are on a decade old Mac. Uhh... Which OS-version are you on? That could play into the whole thing.

Comment: @Zeth - with a 5770 that Mac is limited to High Sierra. Need to upgrade the card to an HD 7950 or similar [& not an Nvidia] to get Mojave. I honestly wouldn't bother sweating over the visual difference between 60 & 75 Hz. Even clean & crisp you won't be able to see the difference. High screen refresh rates are for gamers who don't understand why they think they need it.